# Python script that calls vcvarsall.bat fails from GitLab CI

Tags: python, visual-c++, cmake, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a Python script that works from `cmd.exe` and `powershell.exe` but not from a GitLab runner job on Windows.

```py
def build():
    for c in ["Debug", "Release"]:
        subprocess.check_call(
            f'vcvarsall.bat x64 && \
            cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" \
                -B{os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))}/src/x64/{c} \
                -S{os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))}/src \
                -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE={c} & \
            cmake --build {os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))}/src/x64/{c}',
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    build()
```

If I run the script from `cmd.exe` or `powershell.exe` like so: `python build.py`, everything works as expected - `vcvarsall.bat` sets up the environment correctly so the subsequent `cmake` call has all of the required environment variables.

Running the script from a GitLab runner job on Windows using the `.gitlab-ci.yml` below fails.

```yaml
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - python build.py
  tags:
    - windows
```

In the GitLab UI job stdout, I can confirm `vcvarsall.bat` is being run and `cmake` after that:

[image]

In the `CMakeError.log`, the following error is reported:

[image]

The above link error makes me think that running `vcvarsall.bat` from the GitLab runner job is not completely configuring the environment - it is changing the environment, but not enough to make the subsequent `cmake` complete successfully. I can see many differences between the environment configured by `vcvarsall.bat` when executed from the GitLab runner job and `cmd.exe`.

For example, the left is the environment defined when running the script from the GitLab runner job, and the right from `cmd.exe`:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Why do these environmental discrepancies exist, and how can I fix them?

Answer (score 0):

The GitLab runner jobs will not inherit user environment variables or profiles. For example, powershell on Windows runners is always run with the `NoProfile` switch.

You must add the variables explicitly in the runner configuration (or anywhere else env variables can be defined) or add them to system environment variables

Comment: But in my case, I'm not relying on having pre-set environment variables. Instead, I expect the call to `vcvarsall.bat` to configure the environment for the GitLab runner job.